# Adding dynamic element ids to the dom in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a repeating view with a container inside. Also, I added elements with behaviors to this container.

```
RepeatingView listItems = new RepeatingView("listItems");
    listItems.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    listItems.setRenderBodyOnly(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < typeList.size(); i++) {
        WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer(listItems.newChildId());
        container.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        Label typeLabel = (Label) new Label("typeLabel" + i, "label");
        container.add(typeLabel);
        container.add(createMultiChoiceForCustomType("choice" + i, i));
        listItems.add(container);
    }
    add(listItems);
```

and HTML

```
<div class="otherPermissionsOption">
      <div wicket:id="listItems"></div>
</div>
```

and I've got an error in the console

> Wicket.Ajax:  Cannot bind a listener for event "change.select2" on element "id13c" because the element is not in the DOM

How can I put dynamic container+elements ids on the HTML page to get rid of this error? Is it possible to have dynamic containers in Wicket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 listItems.setOutputMarkupId(true);
 listItems.setRenderBodyOnly(true);
```

These two lines contradict.

`listItems.setOutputMarkupId(true);` says - I want Wicket to add `id` attribute to the HTML element and to generate unique value for it

`listItems.setRenderBodyOnly(true);` says - I do not need the HTML element tag (will all its attributes). I want Wicket to render just the children components of this component. You need to remove it.

Your markup should contain HTML elements for the children:

```
<div class="otherPermissionsOption">
  <div wicket:id="listItems">
    <span wicket:id="typeLabel"></span>
    <div wicket:id="choice"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there is no need to add `+ i` to the component ids in the Java code.

Also there is no need of casting at:

```
... = (Label) new Label("typeLabel" + i, "label");
```

Comment: So setOutputMarkupId(true) equals to my attempts to generate unique id for each element. Renderbody was just my experiment to solve the issue. 
Thank you for your explanation, didn't know about wicket id generation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code sample for future diggers

JAVA

```
    RepeatingView listItems = new RepeatingView("documentAppItemContainer");

    for (int i = 0; i < typeList.size(); i++) {
        WebMarkupContainer documentAppContainer = new WebMarkupContainer(listItems.newChildId());
        WebMarkupContainer documentAppPanel = new WebMarkupContainer("documentAppItem");
        Label typeLabel = new Label("documentAppLabel", "label");
        documentAppPanel.add(typeLabel);
        documentAppPanel.add(createMultiChoiceForCustomType("documentAppSettings", i));
        documentAppContainer.add(documentAppPanel);
        listItems.add(documentAppContainer);
    }
    add(listItems);
```

HTML

```
    <div wicket:id="documentAppItemContainer">
        <div wicket:id="documentAppItem">
            <wicket:component wicket:id="documentAppLabel"/>
            <wicket:component wicket:id="documentAppSettings"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using repeaters to achieve dynamic markups is wide documented in Wicket ecosystem, but sometimes better is

```
public class GridPanel extends Panel implements IMarkupResourceStreamProvider {
...

@Override
    public IResourceStream getMarkupResourceStream(MarkupContainer markupContainer, Class<?> aClass) {
        return ... 
    }
}
```

https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/apidocs/9.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/IMarkupResourceStreamProvider.html